# How can I virtually point http://example.com to http://ex2.com/example in apache server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I am dealing with a CMS - mostly custom works. One installation of the CMS can handle more than one sites.

Now when deploying the setup on an apache server - I am facing some problems. 
My CMS setup is in `http://ex2.com` and the sites in it are like `/example`, `/process`, etc. So if I hit to `http://ex2.com/example` I get the first site.

My requirement is to find a way so that I can get the first site (for example) through `http://example.com` [*not necessarily a valid domain - it can be a virtual one*].

So using `virtualhost` or `htaccess` -- I need to point the `http://example.com` to `http://ex2.com/example`.

Is that possible? I am using `apache2.4`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this problem using `mod_proxy` and `virtualhost`.

In my `/etc/hosts` file - defined the designated virtual hostname like:

```
127.0.2.1   example.com www.example.com
127.0.2.2   process.com www.process.com
```

Then in my `/etc/apache/sites-available/ex.conf` file wrote the following virtual host definition:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.2.1:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com www.example.com 

    <location />
        ProxyPass http://ex2.com/example/
        ProxyPassReverse http://ex2.com/example/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </location>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 127.0.2.2:80>
  ServerName process.com
  ServerAlias process.com www.process.com 

    <location />
        ProxyPass http://ex2.com/process/
        ProxyPassReverse http://ex2.com/process/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And after enabling the `conf` file by `sudo a2ensite ex` command and restarting `apache` - Bingo! I got what I was looking for.

Thanks guys who participated in this.